# Only the last row gets added to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract some data from a JSON web response, in my for loop going trough the data, the data i want gets printed out. but when i print the df.head() its missing some rows

```
modules = i['modules']    
for j in modules:
    row2 = pd.DataFrame([j['dashboard_data']])
    row2['ID'] = j['_id']
    row2.rename(columns={"Temperature":"temp_outside", "Humidity": "humidity_outside"}, inplace=True)
    print(row2)

row2.head(5)
```

the output is from print(row2)

```
     time_utc  temp_outside  humidity_outside  min_temp  max_temp  \
0  1571909773          11.5                72       8.2      11.5   

   date_max_temp  date_min_temp temp_trend                 ID  
0     1571909773     1571868001         up  00:00:00:0f:00:f0  
     time_utc  Rain  sum_rain_1  sum_rain_24                 ID
0  1571909805     0           0            0  00:00:00:00:0d:0c
     time_utc  WindStrength  WindAngle  GustStrength  GustAngle  max_wind_str  \
0  1571909805            16        266            39        193            44   

   max_wind_angle  date_max_wind_str                 ID  
0             221         1571903768  00:00:00:00:ba:a0
```

the output from row2.head(5)

```
    time_utc    WindStrength    WindAngle   GustStrength    GustAngle   max_wind_str    max_wind_angle  date_max_wind_str   ID
0   1571909805  16  266 39  193 44  221 1571903768  00:00:00:00:ba:a0
```

i expected there to be 3 rows in row2.head(5) but i only get 1.

here is a link to an example of how the response looks
[Netatmo Response](https://dev.netatmo.com/en-US/resources/technical/reference/weather/getstationsdata)

Comment: Maybe the print result comes from different iterations of the loop, and in the last one there is only one row.

Comment: after your comment, i tried to append  row2 into another dataframe(while in the loop, same place as the print is), then print that dataframe. wich returned empty. could you elaborate? i'm apparently to stupid :p

Comment: I recommend that you change the loop to `for i, j in enumerate(modules):`, and add a line `print(i)` as the first line in the loop, so that you will know in what iteration does every row come from.

Comment: ooh, thanks! :) atleast i know what gets printed in each iteration now. so thats something. ill fiddle some more from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for l, j in enumerate(modules):
        #print(l)
        #print('############################')
        row2 = pd.DataFrame([j['dashboard_data']], index=[0])
        row2['ID'] = j['_id']
        row2.rename(columns={"Temperature":"temp_outside", "Humidity": "humidity_outside"}, inplace=True)
        #print(row2)
        df2 = df2.append(row2, sort=True)
```

i made it work. thanks to  [@Aryerez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11945002/aryerez) :)